# Regular Expression to get contents of anchor tag InnerHTML in php

Tags: php, regex

I need to retrieve anchor tag innerHTML using RegExp in php. Consider I have a syntax like

```
   <div class="detailsGray"><span class="detailEmail"><a href="http://example.com"class="fontLink">examples@mail.com</a></span></div>
```

Try to get it by

```
preg_match_all('/class=\"fontLink"\>.*\<\/a\>/', $raw, $matches);
```

but which is not working. Only I need to retrieve examples@mail.com using RegExp and preg_match_all(). Thanks

Comment: do you really need to do it using PHP? Because if it is okay you can use JQuery or simple javascript to get what you want. For example if you want to retrieve the anchor tag just use $('.fontlink').attr('href').. just a suggestion..

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.But, unfortunately I need to use php.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to get contents of div class in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446766/regular-expression-to-get-contents-of-div-class-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a parser. Luckily, PHP has one!

```
$html = '<div class="detailsGray"><span class="detailEmail"><a href="http://example.com" class="fontLink">examples@mail.com</a></span></div>';
echo retrieve_node_text($html, "//a[@class='fontLink']");

// -----------------------------------------------
function retrieve_node_text($html_fragment, $xpath) {
  $fragment = new DOMDocument();
  $fragment->loadHTML($html_fragment);

  if ($fragment) {
    $xp = new DOMXPath($fragment);
    $result = $xp->query($xpath);

    if ($result->length == 1) {
      return $result->item(0)->textContent;
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

returns:

```
examples@mail.com
```

Comment: @Ajith: Don't forget to put some error checking and handling into the code. It's not guaranteed that `loadHTML()` or `query()` run successfully, since both `$html_fragment` and `$xpath` could be broken. Be sure to test with broken input and to handle PHP errors or warnings accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the Regex is a bit of a mess:

`'/class=\"fontLink\">.*?<\/a>/'`

As far as I know there is nothing special about `<>` in regex.

You don't want `.*` as that will go to straight to end of the line and then start working backwards. `.*?` will take the next character if doesn't match until `</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

What is your input ? If it's raw data from the web, regexp is not a reliable way to do that. It would be better to load your dom as a tree.

Answer (score 0):

You need positive lookahead and lookbehind, so your pattern will be like this:

```
(?<=class=\"fontLink\"\>).*(?=\<\/a\>)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach was good enough. This is my solution:

```
preg_match('/class=\"fontLink"\>(.*)\<\/a\>/', $raw, $matches);
$parsedEmail = $matches[1];
```

Just add parenthesis on the parts that you want, so they can be matched alone.
If you only want to match one issue use preg_match() instead of preg_match_all().